# Does OpenShift 3.11 block any SSLv3 traffic on secure routes?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, openshift, openshift-3

I have my system running in OpenShift 3.11.

I have to implement an https/REST integration with a legacy Java 1.6 system, which supports SSLv3 only.

Thus I had to enable SSLv3 encryption on my web server and I'm using passthrough mode for my OpenShift routes.

When I'm running `openssl s_client -connect localhost:4430 -ssl3` inside my pod's terminal to test SSLv3 connection, everything's fine:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=2 CN = Test Root CA 2
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=2 CN = Test Root CA 2
verify return:1
depth=1 DC = ru, DC = sbrf, DC = ca, CN = Sberbank Test Issuing CA 2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = RU, ST = Some-State, L = Moscow, O = Sberbank, OU = MMB, CN = ift-spod.apps.test-ose.ca.sbrf.ru, emailAddress = Melnikov.D.Alek@sberbank.ru
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = RU, ST = Some-State, L = Moscow, O = Sberbank, OU = MMB, CN = ift-spod.apps.test-ose.ca.sbrf.ru, emailAddress = Melnikov.D.Alek@sberbank.ru
   i:DC = ru, DC = sbrf, DC = ca, CN = Sberbank Test Issuing CA 2
 1 s:DC = ru, DC = sbrf, DC = ca, CN = Sberbank Test Issuing CA 2
   i:CN = Test Root CA 2
 2 s:CN = Test Root CA 2
   i:CN = Test Root CA 2
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = RU, ST = Some-State, L = Moscow, O = Sberbank, OU = MMB, CN = ift-spod.apps.test-ose.ca.sbrf.ru, emailAddress = Melnikov.D.Alek@sberbank.ru
issuer=DC = ru, DC = sbrf, DC = ca, CN = Sberbank Test Issuing CA 2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5893 bytes and written 270 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: ED516AC9E327AECF04ACA14AEB9BD5D5FCDD4337DEB0D446E23A23063325A8B0
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 34B45454DA572634B1F1DD24CCF98BEE7CED7B878C16DB554E6D3AF1B1B43E8E1DE2598C2A90CA106137B603472E8BA8
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1576863631
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

But when I'm trying to connect by external interface (or from any other machine), I get:

`openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect ift-spod.apps.test-ose.ca.sbrf.ru:443`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140494325270400:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 58 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1576864292
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: The OpenShift 3.11 HAProxy routers use SNI. Perhaps passing in `-servername` argument will help? Like `-servername ift-spod.apps.test-ose.ca.sbrf.ru`, or `-servername ift-spod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, got a confirmation from a team that managed OpenShift in my organization that  HAProxy was blocking SSLv3.